# WordPress' has_term() is not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom taxonomy for posts defined as follows:

```
// Register custom taxonomy for posts
function custom_taxonomy_page_type_for_posts() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Page Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Page Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        ...

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => false,
        ...
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'page-type' ),
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'page_type', 'post', $args );
}
```

In the following code, I want to add a body class depending on whether on not the current post is assigned a Page Type of "Briefing".

```
/* This either adds the class "vn-briefing" or "vn-not-briefing" to the body tag. */
function add_page_type_css_class($classes) {
    if (is_singular('post')) {
        // Check if the post has a "Page Types" taxonomy assigned with ID 187
        if (has_term('Briefing', 'Page Types')) {
            $classes[] = 'is-briefing';
        } else {
            $classes[] = 'is-not-briefing';
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'add_page_type_css_class');
```

It always returns false even if the post is assigned 'Page Type' of ID=187 Briefing.

I was expecting the function to return true if the post was assigned a Page Type of "Briefing" but it doesn't.

I've also tried:

```
   has_term('Briefing', 'Page Type')
   has_term('Briefing', 'page-type')
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It is definitely `page_type` for the second parameter, I can tell you that. Sometimes it helps to take a look at [what the function does](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/#source), too. In this case, either WordPress can't find the current post, or [`is_object_in_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_object_in_term/) is failing, so maybe try running that manually to debug further

Comment: Try this: `has_term( 'briefing', 'page_type', get_queried_object_id() )`. The use of `get_post()` means it will use the global `$post` if none is provided, but I tend to explicitly indicate the post to be sure (as there are times when the global `$post` will change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct syntax would be **has_term('briefing', 'page_type')**. Here's the updated code:

```
function add_page_type_css_class($classes) {
  if (is_singular('post')) {
    // Check if the post has a "Page Types" taxonomy assigned with slug 'briefing'
    if (has_term('briefing', 'page_type')) {
        $classes[] = 'is-briefing';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'is-not-briefing';
    }
 }
 return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'add_page_type_css_class');
```